# Access websocket @endpoint from REST service

Tags: rest, websocket

I have a @ServerEndpoint running on Jboss which holds websocket connections. The customer doesnt want the push of data to be done through the @ServerEndpoint´s @onMessage, but rather a POST-request to some REST endpoint which then pushes the data to the websocket connections (yes, I dont get it either). So my question is; can I get hold of the websocket sessions from the REST-endpoint without opening a server to server connection to the @ServerEndpoint (cause then the security context of the user is broken)?

So I need something like this:

```
@Controller
@Path("/path")
public class WebsocketController {

@GET
public void doPost(String text) {
    //somehow get all websocket connections to the @ServerEndpoint
    //then for all sessions do: 
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText(text);
    }
}
```

Really what any sensible solution would put in the @OnMessage method of the @ServerEndpoint

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a syncronized list of Sessions I maintain on @OnOpen og @OnClose which holds all open connections. Then I push to these connections from the REST endpoint.

Comment: But how did you manage to access this "synchronized list of Sessions" from your REST endpoint?